# How to make synergy only swap with hotkey+sides

Tags: synergy

I want to make synergy only swap screens while I hold down a key and then going to the right side. I don't want synergy to switch screens while i don't hold down the key. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there's a way to do exactly what you want (i.e. change screen only when a specific key is held down). However, since you have already committed to the concept of using a hotkey when you want to change screens, have you considered disabling mouse-based screen swapping completely and using only hotkeys to change?

This is how my system is set up. My synergy config file lists the four machines I use (server + three clients), but I have no orientation or links set up. Instead, under options I've defined "keystroke(shift+control+alt+KP_1) = switchToScreen(system1)" hotkeys for all four PCs. Now my mouse never leaves the screen I'm on just by moving to the edge of the screen. Instead, to switch I press Ctrl-Alt-Shift-# (where # is a number 1 through 4 on the keypad) to move control to a specific PC.

I'll list my full synergy config file below, so feel free to take it and modify it to your needs.

---

```
# Synergy configuration file

# screen definitions
section: screens
        System4:
        System3:
        System2:
        System1:
end

# screen orientation/links
section: links
        System4:
        System3:
        System2:
        System1:
end

# Options
section: options
        screenSaverSync=false
        relativeMouseMoves = true
#
        keystroke(shift+control+alt+KP_3) = switchToScreen(System3)
        keystroke(shift+control+alt+KP_2) = switchToScreen(System2)
        keystroke(shift+control+alt+KP_1) = switchToScreen(System1)
        keystroke(shift+control+alt+KP_4) = switchToScreen(System4)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a Hotkeys (i.e: Control + Shift + Capslock) for an action lockCursorToScress(toggle). then when you want to walk around your screens, you can lock/unlock by press ctrl + shift + capslock